# android : button remains highlighted even after operation is over

Tags: android

Am writing an Android App where am generating a PDF. On clicking a button, PDF generation is done. But even after the PDF is completely generated and the method returns, the button remains in highlighted (blue) state. I even tried mentioning 'button.clearFocus()' at the end of the method which generates the PDF, but in vain. Can someone please help?

Comment: U should show ur code .

Comment: show us the codes, are you generating the pdf on the main thread? if so your long running operation has probably glitched the UI

Comment: Guess the process of generating your PDF file has not been finished and therefore it's blocking the UI thread causing your Button remains as the focused state. Make sure that every heavy task or network task should be running as its own process rather than the UI process. Post some of your code related to the problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: you mean long running tasks should be run on there own thread, not process. Process is completely different animal.

Answer (score 0):

Try button.setPressed(false);  if you want to change pressed state by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rather than using button.setSelected(true), setSelected(false), just use   

button.setPressed(true), setPressed(false).

otherwise use selector for button background.

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/button_focus" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@color/button_non_focus" android:state_pressed="false"></item>

</selector>
```